# Scripting permissions to execute lambda from aws api gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3, aws-api-gateway

[image]

In the aws UI, I get this message when I want to add a lambda function to aws api gateway integration request. How can I script this using boto3?

Been struggling with doing it using lambda: add_permission but missing something still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using lambda add_permission API or CLI.

The policy should be structured like this:

`...
"AWS:SourceArn":"arn:aws:execute-api:[REGION]:[ACCOUNT_ID]:[API_ID]/*/[HTTP_VERB]/[RESOURCE_PATH]"}},
"Action":"lambda:InvokeFunction",
"Resource":"arn:aws:lambda:[REGION]:[ACCOUNT_ID]:function:[FUNCTION_NAME]",
"Effect":"Allow",
"Principal":{"Service":"apigateway.amazonaws.com"}
...`

Comment: is there difference/gotchas if there is also a custom authorizer involved? my custom authorizer is being executed but the actual lambda under the api end point is not being executed. I get this error in the logs Execution failed due to configuration error: API Gateway does not have permission to assume the provided role

Comment: this was all along working (although error messaging is a bit confusing)...I had to setup proper response mappings for it to return properly.